# I am yours, but you don't often use me

Tags: riddle

> Most people own me
>
> Although I am yours, you don't often use me
>
> Others use it more frequently than you yourself

What am I?

Comment: Should "owe" be "own" or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

is it

> name

because

> our name : we don't use it , others use it often(to call us)

Answer (score 5):

There are number of possible answers:

> A name , email id, mobile number,our address,etc.

or can we call these

> unique identifiers of a person ?

Answer (score 3):

A classical riddle, I think the answer is:

> A name