# By mouth and by hand

Tags: riddle

I found this puzzle on Qzone, a popular social app in China.

> What of your things other people use it by their own mouths, you use
>   it your own hands.

I haven't found a solution to this puzzle yet.

---

Here is the original puzzle, and I expect a better translation:

> 你的什么东西别人用它时就用口，你用它时就用手？

Comment: Just running through my basic chinese it is closer to : what of your things other people use it by their own mouths, you use it your own hands. Its a small difference mainly the what of yours. Which I suspect supports C. Woods answer. Side note based on the fact I know all of those characters indicates to me this is primarily aimed at like 5 year olds...

Comment: @Goinghamateur Yeah, personally I also suspect it targets at pre-school children. This makes Dianafreedom's answer less reasonable :)

Comment: Similar: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35163/i-am-yours-but-you-dont-often-use-me.

Comment: similar how, @dan?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would guess

> your name. Other people call you by your name, but you rarely say it yourself; instead you usually write it down on forms or as a signature.

Answer (score 1):

> A smartphone

Other people use it by their mouths.

> talk on phone

Yourself use it by your hands.

> If you're on the app, you're using the touchscreeen