# Riddle Who am I?

Tags: riddle, word

This is a small and simple riddle

> I belong to you but other people use me more.
> Who am I?

Comment: This strikes me as the same logic as [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35163/i-am-yours-but-you-dont-often-use-me) just in reverse, so I have voted to close as duplicate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it

> Your name

?

All the other people use it frequently. You... Not so much!

Comment: Yes you are right!